# Grunt task to decode base64 and save as a file

Tags: gruntjs, base64, decode

I am trying to save the file from base64 data. is there any grunt module which helps to convert the base64 and help to save as an image or corresponding file.
have come across "grunt-base64" which helps to encode as base64.
Is there any grunt task to convert the base64 and save as a file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nodejs writeFile method helped me to resolve this issue.

`require("fs").writeFile("out.ext", base64Data, 'base64', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this plugin: https://github.com/BrightcoveOS/grunt-base64?